# Will deleting all Elastic indices that match on an Index Pattern also delete the Index Pattern?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-cloud

Context:
I am working in Kibana. It is hooked up to an elastic cluster running in docker.

Here is the objective:

- I currently have an index pattern named `objects-*` that matches on several indices of the form `objects-name`, `objects-pattern`, etc.
- I have created several visualizations that use this index pattern and I don't want these visualizations to begin erroring and become unusable (this tends to happen when I mess with indices or patterns)
- Shortly, the indices described are going to be deleted and the same data is going to be put in to indices of the form `objects-sco-name`, `objects-sco-pattern`, etc. Essentially the characters `sco` and going to be added to the index names.
- Note that these new indices should still match the existing index pattern `objects-*`

Will the existing index pattern be affected by the actions described? Will my Kibana visualizations be affected?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

No it won't affect your visualizations as its based on the index pattern and there will be new index added matching your index-pattern, you can easily test it by creating simulating it with some test index patterns and indices rather than guessing and worrying about it.